# Data exchange standards

Tags: architecture, standards, communication

There are international standards, which define various high-level aspects of information exchange in distributed systems. By "high-level" I mean describing how information should be organized and presented, what interfaces must be provided, how to communicate metadata etc.

For example, energy utilities use OPC (DAIS), CIM; simulations have IEEE 1516 (HLA).
May be some other industry has a well-developed standard for similar interactions?

Comment: This is a very strange question, what kind of answer are you looking for? "Yes"?

Comment: Say, "Yes, there is a standard XYZ 666 for medical systems and it is actually used in commercial projects"

Comment: Thanks for all answers, but exchange of messages in a unified format (like finance and business protols suggested) is a significantly different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Healthcare industry uses [HL7](http://www.hl7.org/)

Real Estate uses [RETS](http://www.rets.org/about)

Comment: I'll accept this one, but thanks for other non-financial answers to this question too.

Comment: "Real Estate tries to use RETS"

Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The building automation and control industry uses [BACnet](http://www.BACnet.org/) which is an [ASHRAE](http://ashrae.org) standard, ANSI standard, and also an ISO standard.

Answer (score 0):

The finance industry uses [SWIFT](http://www.swift.com/) and [FIX](http://www.fixprotocol.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Universal Business Language and dozens of others are documented at [OASIS](http://www.oasis-open.org).
UBL is widely accepted as an invoicing standard, at least, and some countries (at least Denmark) make UBL a legal requirement for invoicing public organisations.

Answer (score 0):

You want [EDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange), though this is a catch-all for a lot of different standards for different domains.

Answer (score 0):

The Appraisal industry uses [MISMO](http://www.mismo.org/) (Mortgage Industry Standards Maintenance Organization).  MISMO was in loose collaboration with RETS (Real Estate Transaction Standard) several years ago.  RETS serves the real estate community, specifically organizing the exchange of listing data between MLS (Multiple Listing System) and interested entities.